# Connector/J depends on libmysqlclient.so?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I wanna research mysql-connector-java depends on .so files

Do you know that mysql-connector is pure java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector/J is pure Java driver. It does not require libmysqlclient.